# SSH Port forwarding / Tunneling with multiple hops

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

[image: SSH-Tunneling]

**Background**

- Three subnets exist in an AZ in AWS. Two of them are private and one is public.
- The Public Subnet has a `Jumpbox` which can be connected to from my local machine via `ssh` using a `pem` file (Sample - `ssh -i my-key-file.pem ec2-user@host1`
- The First private subnet has an EC2 Instance that acts as a Application Server. It can only be reached from the Jumbox via `ssh`. The same `pem` file is used here. (Sample - `ssh -i my-key-file.pem ec2-user@host2`). This command is executed on `host1`.
- The second private subnet hosts an Oracle Instance using AWS RDS Service. It is running on port `1521`. The DB Can only be accessed from the App Server/`host2`.

**How I am working currently**

- `host2` has `sqlplus` client installed.
- First,I connect to `host1`, then to `host2`, and then execute `sqlplus` to execute Queries at the Command line (No GUI).

I am planning to use GUI tools like SQL Developer to connect right from my local machine. I thought using Port forwarding/SSH Tunneling It can be achieved.

I tried using different options, but with no success. The following links are useful:

- https://superuser.com/questions/96489/an-ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops
- https://rufflewind.com/2014-03-02/ssh-port-forwarding

**My Approach to SSH Tunneling**

- `ssh -N -L 9999:127.0.0.1:1234 ec2-user@host1 -i my-key-file.pem -v -v -v`

  - This is executed on my local machine.
  - It does not do much as I can already connect to `host1` using `ssh`. I did not know how to forward many levels. Using this host as my first hop. After this, `ssh` listens on port `9999` which is `Local` to my machine. It forwards any traffic to `host1` to Port `1234`. *My assumption is that, If I use sqlplus on my local machine connecting to `localhost:9999`, the traffic will arrive at `host1:1234`*
  - I used `127.0.0.1` because the target of SSH tunneling is with respect to the SSH Server, which is `host1`. Basically, Both *Target*, *SSH Server* are on the same host.
- `ssh -N -L 1234:db-host:1521 ec2-user@host2 -i my-key-file.pem -v -v- v`

  - This is executed on `host1`
  - After this, ssh forwards any incoming traffic on port `1234` to target host (DB Host)/1521 using `host2` as the Tunnel.
  - Again, my assumption is that, `ssh` is listening on port `1234` on `host1`. Any traffic arriving from anywhere will be delivered to `DB Host` using `host2` as the tunnel.

I executed both commands and did not see any error. I verified which ports are listening using `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`.

After these two, My plan was to connect to the Database using Hostname as `localhost` and Port number as `9999`.

**What's going wrong !**

- But when I try to connect to the DB from my local machine, getting an error from my SQL Client *Got minus one from a read call*. I could not understand the Debug messages from ssh logs.

I believe my understanding of how port forwarding works might not be right. Any inputs would be helpful. 
Thanks for your time !

Comment: Before trying to figure out this complex flow, is there any possibility that they can modify the Security Group on the RDS database to allow a connection from the Jumpbox? If so, only one SSH command would be required.

Comment: **Side-note:** Are you keeping a copy of the PEM file on the Jump Box? If so, this is a potential security problem, since somebody who gains access to that machine would then have access to other machines. It is better to use Agent Forwarding rather than storing the key on other computers.